# Nexus repository anonymous download : bug or feature?

Tags: maven, nexus

When i'm not logged in Nexus repository (v3.17.0-01), I can download any artifact from any private project when I know its URL (I can't browse anything).

Is it a bug ? Is it something that can be disabled ?
I'm not talking about anonymous access which is disabled, but only anonymous download.

Comment: Snapshot or release repositories? Or both?

Comment: If anonymous access is disabled I'd say that's a bug.  However, I'd be sure you don't have anything cached in your browser (use an incognito window).  Also it is possible to disable anonymous browse and have download I believe, but I am trusting your text it's totally disabled :P

Comment: I only tested with a simple file in a raw repository but I cannot reproduce your problem, either in your specific version or the latest one (3.22.1-02). If I disable anoymous access (admin > security > anonymous), I get a 401 error when accessing the artifact url. I made this test with curl from the command line. I can also confirm I get the exact same behaviour on our production where anonymous access is enabled but where we have a custom anonymous role which is only able to access a certain number of repositories. Is there a proxy between nexus and you machine ?

Comment: ok, you're right, maybe we had some custom anonymous role.